# Can I enter Mexico without a visa but with an Italian residence permit?

Tags: visas, italy, mexico, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani citizen with an Italian residence permit (Polizia di Stato). I would like to travel to Mexico over Christmas. I don't have a visa. Will my Italian residence permit allow me to enter Mexico?

Answer (score 9):

Yes you can, You don't need a visa.

> With the purpose of facilitating and promoting travel to Mexico, effective May 2016 all those foreign nationals, regardless of their nationality, visiting Mexico for tourism, business or transit are NOT required to obtain a Mexican visa IF they hold a valid (non-expired) Visa or Permanent Residence of any of this countries: United States of America, Canada, Japan, United Kingdom or Schengen area (European Union).

Source: **[Consulate General Of Mexico in San Francisco](https://consulmex2.sre.gob.mx/sanfrancisco/index.php/visas-traveling-to-mexico)**

Comment: Op doesn't state whether his res. permit is temporary or permanent

Comment: @Coke fair enough, that's a valid point which should be noted

Answer (score 3):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a **permanent**
>   residence permit issued by Italy for a maximum stay of 180
>   days.

So if you have a **permanent** residence permit, you don't need a visa. Otherwise, you **do** need a visa.